# Extract KeyCode from Android On-Screen Keyboard's KeyPress Event

Tags: android, keyboard, android-jetpack-compose, bluetooth-lowenergy, hid

I've developed an Android app that connects to a PC over Bluetooth Low Energy and enables control of the keyboard from the Android device. This app sends physical HID keycodes to the PC instead of text. It's written in Jetpack Compose.

According to the research I've conducted, there doesn't seem to be a straightforward method to retrieve keycodes from key presses on the on-screen keyboard in Android. So, I'm turning to Stack Overflow for help.

Is there a way to obtain the exact keycode when a user presses a key on the on-screen keyboard, regardless of the keyboard layout? If not, is there a way to detect key presses through text changes, and how can I do this across different layouts?

Thank you for any assistance you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

On screen keyboards don't use keycodes, or keypresses.  They mostly use the commitText API on InputConnection.  KeyPresses are for physical keys, such as a hardware USB keyboard."

So no, there isn't, because that's not a concept they use.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. Is there a way to convert a pressed character, committed from the keyboard, to the corresponding keycode, as if it were pressed from a real hardware keyboard? The goal is to send it to the remote PC as an HID keycode (When possible).

Comment: It could be done.  You'd need to first figure out what key was pressed.  The easiest way to do that is to define your own inputConnection for whatever view has focus (done by overriding the onCreateInputConnection function.  Then when commitText is called, send a keycode down for every letter in the text (it can send more than 1 at once).  That would be close to correct, although there are keys that won't work for (delete generally calls deleteSurroundingText and can be hooked similarly.  The action button also has its own hook.  Things like microphone won't send anything ever).

Comment: A way that *might* work is to set the mode of whatever input field you use to TYPE_NULL.  The keyboard then might try to pretend to be a hardware keyboard in compatibility mode.  Or it might not-  not every phone has the same keyboard app, and not all keyboard apps work the same.  If that works, then the Activity's dispatchKeyEvent could be used.  But it's not reliable, it depends on that specific keyboard having that specific fallback for a null field type.

Comment: I understand that I can hook the commitText, then iterate each character from the text, and treat each character.
But the text can be in different languages, eg: written in English / Russian / Hebrew or any other language in the keyboard.
And I need a way to transform character into it's equivalent pysical key (like it was pressed from real hardware keyboard)
Eg:
"s" => KEYCODE_s // English
"ש" => KEYCODE_s // Hebrew
"ф" => KEYCODE_s // Russian
"ñ" => KEYCODE_s // Spanish

Do I have to create my own maps for every possible language, 
Or there's a simpler way?

Comment: Yes, you'd need to do it yourself, or find a library that does it.  There's nothing built in.